# Windows 7 Wi-Fi only connecting when LAN cable plugged in

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, lan, wifi-driver

Wi-Fi connection works when the LAN cable is plugged in but it shows "Limited Access" as soon as it is removed. I would like to troubleshoot this or even provide further details - but I dont know what details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the LAN is plugged in you are not using the WiFi, unless the LAN is not attached to your PC.

So, with no LAN cable, and only wireless, open command prompt (type `cmd` in the Search program and files in the start menu) and type

> ipconfig /all

From here, find your Default gateway

Now, type in *ping default gateway* EG

> ping 192.168.1.0

Please note the results.

Whilst in this screen, please type in

> ping 8.8.8.8

Please note the results.

My guess is, both results are bad and the cause is the signal from your machine to your router is bad.

You may need to get an N range router (my guess is you're on a G), or you need to update your wireless device on your machine. Lastly, try moving the router closer to your computer, or move your computer closer to your router, just to see if it is a distance issue.

Lastly, try and connect using a smart phone, tablet, laptop/netbook and see if you have any problems with the connection as well.